# Ads not showing properly

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, admob

I am trying to include interstitial ads in the middle of my simple quiz app. After 10 questions an interstitial ad should show up. The ad shows up, but goes away within few seconds without being dismissed. What is wrong?

```
private void OnAdReceived(object sender, AdEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Ad received successfully");
    ad.ShowAd();
}
```

```
    private void next_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        option1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        option2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        option3.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        option4.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        question.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        a.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        b.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        c.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        d.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        button.Visibility = Visibility.Visible ;
        next.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        answer.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        VibrationDevice v = VibrationDevice.GetDefault();
        v.Vibrate(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1));
        Random rnd = new Random();
        if(tot%10==0)
        {
            ad = new InterstitialAd("admob_id");
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
            // Enable test ads.
            adRequest.ForceTesting = true;

            ad.ReceivedAd += OnAdReceived;
            ad.LoadAd(adRequest);
            ad.DismissingOverlay += ad_DismissingOverlay;
        }

        num = shuffle[tot];
        tot++;
        question.Text = sat[num];
        option1.Text = opt[num, 0];
        option2.Text = opt[num, 1];
        option3.Text = opt[num, 2];
        option4.Text = opt[num, 3];

        a.IsChecked = true;
    }
```

Comment: ad.DismissingOverlay is defined but does nothing

Comment: Please add the rest of your code, your if statement is lonely.

Comment: @Mathemats edit has been done .